# How can I get text entered in one text field copied in realtime to multiple text fields?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I have so far which mirrors (copy data) the other text field, but I want to do this in multiple (more than four) fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyData(from,to) { to.value = from.value; }
</script>

<input type="text name="Company_Name__1" autofocus="focus" value="" size="20" required 
onChange="copyData(this,document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__15)" onKeyUp="copyData(this,document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__15)">

<input type="text" name="Company_Name__15" value="" size="20" required
onChange="copyData(this,document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__1)" onKeyUp="copyData(this,document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__1)">
```

Comment: So you want to copy from one textfield to multiple destination textfields?

Answer (score 2):

You could use as parameter an array of element ids. Something like this

```
copyData(this, ['id1', 'id2']);
```

Then, you should iterate the array on a for loop and use `document.getElementById` to get the element and copy the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep this same structure:

```
function copyData(from,to) {
    to.value = from.value;
}
```

Then reasonably the `to` value would have to be multiple values.  Which means an array.  Something like this:

```
function copyData(from,to) {
    for (var i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        to[i].value = from.value;
    }
}
```

Then to use this you'd just pass it an array instead of a single element:

```
<input type="text name="Company_Name__1" autofocus="focus" value="" size="20" required
       onChange="copyData(this,[document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__15, document.someOtherElement])"
       onKeyUp="copyData(this,[document.Broker_Opportunity.Company_Name__15, document.someOtherElement])">
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your HTML code use a common `class` value to identify the destination text fields:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text name="Company_Name__1" autofocus="focus" value="" size="20" required
       onChange="copyData(this,'your_class')"
       onKeyUp="copyData(this,'your_class')">
```

JS Code:

```
    function copyData(from, dest_class) {
        var toArr = document.getElementsByClassName(dest_class);
        for (var i = 0; i < toArr.length; i++) {
            toArr[i].value = from.value;
        }
    }
```